# Suppose $B$ is the region of an unit ball $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1$, $\partial B $ is the surface of the ball.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $B$ is the region of an unit ball $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1$,  $\partial B $  is the surface of the ball. $f$ is a homogeneous function with degree k, i.e $f(ax,ay,az)=a^kf(x,y,z) $.
Prove 
$$\iint_{\partial B}f(x,y,z) \text dS=\iiint_{B}\Delta f \,dxdydz $$
which $$\Delta f= \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial^2x}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial^2y}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial^2z}$$
First intuition is the application of  Gauss's theorem...

Comment: Are you sure $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary? I would have guessed it should show in the resulting formula as well.

Comment: Since it looks formal , I do believe it has been shown in some text. Actually I met it becanuse it is a question from a past year's exam. And I still haven't find answer. Also  k is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

I think your $k$ has to be $1$, to get your formula. Let me try a calculation:
By Gauss Theorem we have
$$\int_B \Delta f\,dx = \int_{\partial B} \nabla f\cdot n\, dS$$
with $n$ being the outer normal of $B$, hence $n(x)=x\in\partial B$.
The homogenity yields
$$f(ax)=a^kf(x).$$
Let us derive $a\mapsto f(ax)$ by $a$ by chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(f(ax))=x\cdot\nabla f(ax) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a} a^k f(x)=ka^{k-1}f(x).$$
At $a=1$ we therefore get
$$x\cdot\nabla f(x) = kf(x).$$
By going back to Gauss's Theorem we obtain
$$\int_B \Delta f\, dx=\int_{\partial B} \nabla f\cdot n\, dS= \int_{\partial B} \nabla f\cdot x\, dS = \int_{\partial B} kf(x)\, dS,$$
hence the formula looks different if $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary.